# Number of roots in the first quadrant

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find how many roots of the equation $z^4+z^3+1=0$ lies in the first quadrant.

Using Rouche's Theorem how to find ?

Comment: Consider the region defined by the line segments $(0,0)\to(0,R)$, $(0,0)\to(R,0)$, and by the quarter of the circle of radius $R$ in quadrant 1 for $R>1$. Apply Rouche's Theorem on this region, by noting that on the boundary of the region, $|z^4+1|>|z^3|$, telling us that in this region, $z^4+1$ and $z^4+z^3+1$ have the same number of roots in the region, so the equation has $1$ root in the first quadrant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the family of polynomials $z^4+tz^3+1$. For $t=0$ we know the solutions $z=\sqrt{\frac12}(\pm1\pm i)$ which has one root per quadrant. We additionally know that the set of roots is continuous in the coefficients of the polynomial.

Now if changing $t$ from $0$ to $1$ were to change the number of roots in the first quadrant, one of the other roots would have to pass the positive $x$ or $y$ axis. However, on the positive $x$ axis the real part $1+x^3+x^4$ and on the $y$ axis the real part $1+y^4$ are never zero. Thus $$|z^4+tz^3+1|\ge |z^4+1|-t|z|^3>0$$ on the boundary of the first quadrant for $t\in [0,1]$. There is no change in the number of roots over this homotopy.

[image: plot of root paths]

<sub>*roots of $z^4+tz^3+1$ for red: $t=0$ over blue to green: $t=1$*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

All the roots of the given polynomial lie inside $|z|\leq 2$: if we assume $|z|>2$ and $z^4=-(z^3+1)$, we get $2<|z|=|z^{-3}+1|<\frac{9}{8}$ which is a contradiction. Additionally it is simple to check that the roots are simple and there are no purely real or purely imaginary roots, so the number of roots in the first quadrant is given by
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial Q}\frac{4z^3+3z^2}{z^4+z^3+1}\,dz $$
where $Q$ is the square with vertices in $(0,0),(2,0),(2,2),(0,2)$. It is enough to approximate the (imaginary parts of the) four integrals associated to the sides of $Q$ with decent accuracy (for instance, through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton-Cotes_formulas) to discover that there is exactly one root per quadrant.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here I present a more standard solution to this problem:

Let $p(z):=z^4+z^3+1$. Consider the following path

[image]

Since $p(x)>0$ and $p(ix)=x^4+1-ix^3\neq 0$ for $x\geq 0$, we deduce that $p$ has no roots on $\gamma_R$. Therefore, we can apply the Argument Principle to obtain that the number of roots of $p$ in the first cuadrant is the winding number of $0$ around $p\circ \gamma_R$, for sufficiently big $R$.

Besides, for big $R$ the argument variation of $p\circ \text{quarter circle}$ is approximately $\Delta \arg z^4=4\frac{\pi}{2}=2\pi$. Therefore, this fact combined with $p(x)>0$, $p(ix)\in 4\text{th quadrant}$ tells us that **$p$ has exactly one root in the first quadrant**.